# Region between curves $y=(x^3+x^2-1)$ and $y=2x^2+2x-1$ is not $\frac{5}{12}$....? Checked with wolfram alpha it is correct is the question wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The question:
[image]

I've tried to differentiate the two curves and got $\frac{5}{12}$ which is definitely the correct answer.. What did I do wrong here?.

The curve is plotted below:
[image]

Comment: There's third intersection at $(2,11)$.

Comment: Area between $(-1,0)$ is $\frac{5}{12}$, whereas $(0,2)$ is $-\frac{8}{3}$.

Comment: Therefore $5/12+8/3=37/12$ and you are done!

Comment: Oh bugger!! thanks @NgChungTak

Comment: Take home message. Desmos is great and all but *remember to zoom out*. Or, better still, just roll up your sleeves and solve the equation to find all intersection points. In this, case, all roots are integers, meaning you were meant to have done that in the first place.

Comment: The fact that _both_ of the constant terms in the polynomials are the same means that $ \ x \ $ can be factored out of the cubic polynomial resulting from equating the two polynomials, leaving only a quadratic to deal with.  They really _did_ intend to make the intersections easy to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the intersections of both polynomials: $$x^3 + x^2 - 1 = 2x^2 + 2x - 1 \implies x^3 - x^2 - 2x = 0\implies x(x-2)(x+1)=0, \  x = -1,0,2.$$

By substituting in $x = -0.5, 1$, when $x \in (-1, 0)$, the LHS is on top, and when $x \in (0, 2)$, the RHS is on top. So the (signed) area between the curves is:

$$\int_{-1}^0 x^3 - x^2 - 2x \ dx + \int_0^2 -(x^3 - x^2 - 2x) \ dx$$
$$=\left[x^4/4 - x^3/3 - x^2 \right]_{-1}^0 - \left[x^4/4 - x^3/3 - x^2 \right]_0^2$$
$$=-(1/4 + 1/3 - 1) - (4-8/3-4) = \boxed{\frac{37}{12}}.$$